# How to print the element name when using axes?

Tags: xslt

I would like to display the name of the element, which is 4 steps back. I can display the content of the element:

```
<xsl:value-of select="preceding::*[4]/text()" />
```

and also the attribute of the element:

```
<xsl:value-of select="preceding::*[4]/@id" />
```

but this

```
<xsl:value-of select="preceding::*[4]/name()" />
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Your syntax will work in XSLT 2.0, but not in 1.0.

Comment: @Michael Kay - you mean what?

Comment: Which part of my statement didn't you understand?

Comment: I'm using XLST version 1.0 and it worked

Comment: You said that `preceding::*[4]/name()` didn't work. It won't work in 1.0, it does work in 2.0.

Comment: so my last code should work in XSLT 2.0? great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the contents, use `<xsl:value-of select="preceding::*[4]"/>`, to display its name, call the `name` function on the element: `<xsl:value-of select="name(preceding::*[4])"/>`.